# How to avoid The SFSafariViewController's parent view controller was dismissed. issue?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, fbsdkloginkit

I have UINavigationController as a RootViewController. My app goes to FB App and returns to through this ViewController. But It does not drop the completion handler of Facebook SDK.

But I am taking FBSDKError as in the title.

How can I construct navigation cycle in order to avoid this error?

Could you please help me?

BR,

Comment: did you find any solution for this.i am facing same issue.please help.

Comment: I have started checking the access token, since It returns to my app, but not able to enter handler, If currentAccessToken is not nil, proceed to flow... @BK_Suresh

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue occurring when added this to the info plist -

Application does not run in background - YES or source code

```
<key>UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend</key>
<true/>
```

Hope this would help someone, obviously you have to measure if you need this setting in the plist or not

Set this to NO / `<false/>` and this problem goes